# My company name is being used in email address to send fake job offers to random people. How do i stop this

Tags: audit

I have received complaints from people that they are getting job offer letters from my company email address. How can i stop this ?

Comment: Does your company use something like DMARC?

Comment: If you use your own mail server, you could've been compromised. Contact a local IT security professional to help you diagnose your systems.

Answer (score 1):

If your server has its mail relays open, it might be used to send spam emails. For more information take a look:

https://uk.godaddy.com/help/testing-your-server-for-open-relays-8495